# What's the loop invariant for this code?

Tags: loops, while-loop, proof, loop-invariant

I need to come up with a loop invariant for a given piece of code:

```
//pre: x & y >= 0
//post: z = x^y
//computes pow(x, y), x^y
int pow(int x, int y){
    int z = 1;
    while(y > 0){
        if(y%2==0){
            y /= 2;
            x = x*x;
        }else{
            z = z*x;
            y -= 1;
        }
    }
    return z;
}
```

My invariant is:

```
{(ypre - 0 = 0 & x = x^(ypre  -y)) OR (ypre - y != 0 & x^(n + m) = x^(ypre - y), where (n=ypre-y) and (m=integer value of z/x))}
```

This is a messy invariant, and I'm not 100% sure it's correct. Is there a better invariant that would cover the post condition of z = x^y

Comment: Hopefully this is the correct site to post this in.

Comment: x^y is... x xor y? (I'm not that silly, but it would sure as hell help to say what you mean)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest one loop variant is

- that `x' ^ y' == (x ^ y)/z` (where `x'` and `y'` are the modified inputs after any iteration)
- that `x' >= x` and `0 <= y' < y` (this proves that the algorithm will finish)

Comment: what about when x = 2, y = 3? on the third iteration x=4, y=1 so 4^1 != 2^1.

Comment: @Brandon oops I left out the factor `z` of the equation. Fixed.

Comment: Is there anything you can tell me about how you came to this conclusion? This solution is so clean and simple.

Comment: Look at the two branches. Ask yourself (a) why will is it guaranteed to end (b) why is the answer still correct?